# Set Array's Length property

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to change an array's Length property with some technique?

I need to pass first x members of an array to a method. The project requirements prevent me from **allocating any heap allocation** so I can't use any `Array.Resize()` or create a new array.

Also **I can't change the SetVertices code** because it belongs to another library. It needs `V[]`. I can't pass `IList<V>` or `V*` to it.

```
public void BuildIt(V[] verts,int x){
    verts.Length = x; //Compile error
    mesh.SetVertices(verts);
}
```

Of course the code won't compile. I need some technique like reflection or extension methods to disguise the array as smaller **without** actually creating an smaller array. I want SetVertices() method to think the array has x members even though it has more.

**EDIT:**

Tested the following approaches and they don't work:

- stackalloc doesn't work because it doesn't create (or I couldn't get) a real array.
- Peeking into mono project I found out that array's Length property is calling GetLenght() and GetRank() methods to determine the length. Being a bad practice aside, I can't override this method with extension methods because instance methods have precedence over extension methods(or is there a way to force otherwise?).

Gonna try code injection next.

**EDIT2:**

Tried to emit code into `Array.GetLength()` and `Array.Length`. It seems there is no easy, reliable, cross platform and clean way to change an existing method body at runtime.

Comment: I think it is impossible.

Comment: It's almost impossible to write any meaningful C# without allocating something. How strict is that, what is the underlying reason?

Comment: does "x" remain the same or it changes often from one call to another?

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is a game using Unity3d game. GC can have pretty devastating impact on user experience because it freezes game when GC triggers collect. so it is preferred to have a cache of objects rather that creating and dereferencing. The verts array comes from a cache of fixed length arrays.

Comment: The problem as stated can't be solved. Something will have to give. You should answer @alexm.

Comment: @alexm It is different for every invocation

Comment: @HenkHolterman It is a real case happening to our project.

Comment: I cannot see how you can avoid allocation without changing vendor's API. I would ask the vendor to add an overload SetVertices(V[] verts, int startIndex, int count);

Comment: BTW: Unity site says the signature is (*List<Vector3>* inVertices). Are you using an older version? (see: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.SetVertices.html)

Comment: @alexm You are right about Vector3. I simplified the case to make it more understandable.

Comment: @mortezakhosravi i think the emphasis in alexms comment was on list, not on vector3

Answer (score 1):

If you really have to do this with maximum performance - then you must know memory layout for **particular** CLR you use (seems to be some version of Mono in your case). Then you are able to do some unsafe code that change and restore array length. But it's **not maintainable** and **dangerous**.

Comment: Probably I must make some words bold.
**particular CLR**,
**not maintainable**,
**dangerous**

Answer (score 1):

If the arrays and x are not changing and their number is not to big, then you could allocate them once globally, not locally. So, you would invest memory and gain performance.